# Story ID: The world is fully automated, most people have left earth, and a boy needs to travel to Japan

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a (short) story I read a few years ago, not sure exactly how old it is, probably post 2010, it may have been written as a web serial, etc. I thought the title was something like "Empty Roads", but Google is failing me.

The story is about a boy in Mexico that wants to visit a girl in Japan he met online, but it's the future and the world is nearly empty. Everything is automated and almost all the people have left, either uploaded into computers, or on ships to other planets.

It starts out with him walking to local university to look for info on how to travel to Japan. There is a snaking path, but the oak trees are dead and gone because there is no one left to plant new ones, but the robots keep the lawn nice. There was an earthquake in the past, but the buildings self-healed using genetically modified snail shells.

At the library, the automated assistant gives him info about how people travel the world, it's very out of date, but he learns that he needs to get an airline ticket, but doesn't know how to, as the airlines are all automated, but there are no scheduled flights, because there are no people left to fly places.

He takes an automated train to California(?), to go to the airline HQ. The airline owners are now all uploaded, it's scary, but he is given a task, to go and check on something in exchange for a ticket.

He flies to some city in the US, maybe Chicago, and goes to take the subway, but it's not maintained, and he falls through the floor. A woman saves him, she is there to let nature reclaim the city, she is turning off the power etc. She has a bunch of spider robots to help her.

They go to the site he is meant to check, it has automated defenses, the woman helps to destroy the defense systems. They go down into a bunker, inside it is a data-center, and an uploaded man talks to him, about how the other uploaded people are afraid of him, because he is better then them, because they were old and unwell when uploaded, but he was younger.

The other uploads hid a virus on the boy, and it is taking over the uploaded man's systems. He asks the boy to take the backup memory to safety. The boy does it, and is finally able to get to Japan.